# What is the best way to change a column type in Laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I have a User table in my DB:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fullName');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 50);
        $table->enum('role',['boss','employee','customer'])->default('customer');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
```

I need to change 'role' column type  to 'text' and after that, run the new migration in Laravel. If I want to have no effect on previous data, what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to:

1. Create a new text column named "roleTemp"
2. Run a query to set this column for each record - based on the "role" column
3. Remove the "role" column
4. Rename "roleTemp" to "role"

Now simply change your database schema as is:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('fullName');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password', 50);
$table->string('role');
$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();
```

Basically you duplicate the role values to a (temporarily) column and rename it. At least it is safe and won't take a lot of time.

Answer (score 6):

It is as simple as following, create a new migration with this one line. Note the `->change()` function, that makes it a ALTER query.

```
Schema::table('usertable', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('role')->default('author')->change();
});
```

Remember the size for string() by default is 255, and if your enum value is greater than that, it will truncate the enum value to 255 characters.

**Update:**
You need to install `doctrine/dbal` for this to work see [Laravel Migration - Modify Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#modifying-columns%20and)

To install doctrine/dbal just do `composer require doctrine/dbal`

**Note**: Modifying any column in a table that also has a column of type enum is not currently supported.

Comment: I applied your suggestion but I faced with this error:
 `[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.`

Comment: See my updates, this is the right laravally way to do this.

Comment: I did that installation, but didn't work! 
in your link( [https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#modifying-columns] ) you can read that : `Modifying any column in a table that also has a column of type enum is not currently supported.`